# UIButton above UIScrollView. Touch up event doesn't happen

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uibutton, autolayout

I have a scrollview in story board. UIButton is located above this scrollview ("Close"):

[image]

I also added imagesView as subViews for this scrollview in code:

```
        for i in 0..<dataImages.count{


        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: dataImages[i]+".jpg")
        let xPos = CGFloat(i)*self.view.bounds.size.width

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPos, y: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: sv.frame.size.height)
        sv.contentSize.width = view.frame.size.width*CGFloat(i+1)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        sv.addSubview(imageView)

    }
```

Unfortunately, the UIButton touch up inside event doesn't work when the button is above the scrollview (if I move it below it works). How can I fix it?

Comment: you need to bring the view to up by adding this ```view.bringSubviewToFront(<#T##view: UIView##UIView#>)```

Comment: @fakiho Unfortunately, it didn't help

Comment: I wish I can help you but I can really see what is going on, but I'll teach a way to check what is going on with your views,

Answer (score 0):

I wish I can help you but I can really see what is going on, but I'll teach a way to check what is going on with your views, first, you run the app then you go to where you wanna debug your hierarchy and on Xcode, you select debug from the top the screen -> view Debugging -> Capture Hierarchy, what this actually does is capture all the views and for this matter, you can check whether the scroll view is on top of the button or not